# Implementing 2 Java Classes

Tags: java, arrays, class, variable-assignment

I'm learning java and trying to implement two java classes.

- Student: `firstName`, `lastName`, `departmentIn`, `yearGraduation`, an array of UAClass this student is taking, an array of integers corresponding to the grades received for these classes
- UAClass: `teacherFirstName`, `teacherLastName`, `semesterOffered`, `numCredits`

In the Student class, implement a method that calculates GPA. In the Student’s `main()` method, initiate one Student object and print out her GPA.

In my student.java class I have:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Student {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String departmentIn;
private String yearGraduation;
private float [] grade;
private int counter = 0;
private String Student;

public Student(String my_firstName, String my_lastName, String my_deptIn, String my_yearGrad) {
firstName = my_firstName;
lastName = my_lastName;
departmentIn = my_deptIn;
yearGraduation = my_yearGrad;
grade = new float[5];                    
}

public String toString(){

    String value;
    value  = "First Name: " + firstName + "\n";
    value += "Last Name : " + lastName + "\n";
    value += "Department: " + departmentIn + "\n";
    value += "Grad. Year: " + yearGraduation + "\n";
    return value;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
 Student my1 = new Student("Bob", "Hope", "MBA", "2018");
     Student my2 = new Student("John", "Smith", "MBA", "2020");
     Student my3 = new Student("Jane", "Doe", "MBA", "2021");

     UAClass cy1 = new UAClass[4];
     String[] secondArray = cy1.getarrayClass();


     System.out.println(my1);
     System.out.println(my2);
     System.out.println(my3);
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cy1));

 }
 }
```

And in my UAClass.java class I have:

```
import java.util.*;

public class UAClass {
private String teacherFirstName;
private String teacherLastName;
private String semesterOffered;
private String numCredits;  
private String[] arrayClass = {"MBA 501","MBA 505","MBA 513","MBA 545"};

public UAClass(String teacherF, String teacherL, String semesterO, String numC) {
    teacherFirstName = teacherF;
    teacherLastName = teacherL;
    semesterOffered = semesterO;
    numCredits = numC;
}    

public String[] getarrayClass(){
    return arrayClass.clone();
}     


}
```

What I am trying to do is to create an Array in '`UAClass`' and having it printed into '`Student`' but I can't seem to get it working.

---

I've modified the code as Amit suggested. When I run it, I get this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: Array.getarrayClass at Homework2.Student.main(Student.java:66)
```

It seems to be having an issue with String[] secondArray = cy1.***getarrayClass***();

---

I took out the line `String[] secondArray = cy1.getarrayClass()` and it seems to run fine but now all I get is `[null, null, null, null]`

Comment: Can you give the error details? Is it exception you are getting at run time or code is not getting compiled? Also there is problem in one of the line `UAClass cy1 = new UAClass[4];` It should be `UAClass cy1 = new UAClass('X', 'Y', 'Z', 'L');`

Comment: It should be UAClass [] cy1 = new UAClass[4];

Comment: Although you did provide some error detail it doesn't really pertain to your original issue. I have no idea what the real problem is that you're trying to solve only that you made changes and that caused new problems. http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: @D.B. My issue is that I want to create an array in UAClass that has a short list of classes (ie 501, 507A, etc) then have those classes outputted into Student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your UAClass has one constructor that takes `String teacherF, String teacherL, String semesterO, String numC` as parameters.

So you need to call this constructor like this:

```
UAClass cy1 = new UAClass("Teacher F", "Teacher L", "Semester", "NumC");
```

Secondly, you use an String[] type. This is a low-level array type. You can do this in Java, but normally people rather use a `List` type, and then not the raw type, but better like `List<String>`. List is actually an interface, but you can reference it as the Arrays class returns an implementation of the List class.

You should then use:

```
private List<String> arrayClass = Arrays.asList("MBA 501","MBA 505","MBA 513","MBA 545");
```

And you return a clone of the array. I presume you do this because you don't want the array to be changed. I would just return a concatenated String with values. Here is a nice example with a stream.

```
public String getClasses() {
    return arrayClass.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

Now in the Student class you can just print the list of classes like this:

```
System.out.println(cy1.getClasses());
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Sven. I'm assuming after I do the stream, I would then use 'get' inside Student to bring the list of classes over?

Comment: I added how to get the list of classes from the UAClass-class.

Answer (score 0):

When you change your code like that it will work but I couldn't understand what you are trying to do in your code.

```
UAClass cy1 = new UAClass("Bob", "", "", "");
String[] secondArray = cy1.getarrayClass();
System.out.println(my1);
System.out.println(my2);
System.out.println(my3);
System.out.println(cy1.getarrayClass());
```

Comment: I'm trying to create an array of classes in UAClass and have it outputted into Student. I hope this clears it up.